# What is difference between setImageCompressionQuality vs setCompressionQuality - Imagick

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I found two methods in Imagick for set image compression quality

A ) setImageCompressionQuality

B ) setCompressionQuality

so I want to know which one is best and why in below condition

I read that `setCompressionQuality` method only works for new images (?)

I am trying to compress a file jpeg/png

```
$im = new Imagick();

$im->readImage($file); // path/to/file
$im->setImageCompressionQuality($quality); // 90,80,70 e.g.

$im->writeImage($file);
```

Comment: According to the Imagick php page: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php one is for an object and the other is for an image. "I read that setCompressionQuality method only works for new images (?)" Yes as it says on the above page. So only one will work in your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `setImageCompressionQuality` sets compression quality for your current image. This method is a wrapper for `MagickWand`'s `MagickSetImageCompressionQuality` function. [Source code](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickWand/magick-image.c#L9448) is:

```
WandExport MagickBooleanType MagickSetImageCompressionQuality(MagickWand *wand,
  const size_t quality)
{
  assert(wand != (MagickWand *) NULL);
  assert(wand->signature == MagickWandSignature);
  if (wand->debug != MagickFalse)
    (void) LogMagickEvent(WandEvent,GetMagickModule(),"%s",wand->name);
  if (wand->images == (Image *) NULL)
    ThrowWandException(WandError,"ContainsNoImages",wand->name);

  //This line sets the quality for the instance 'images'  
  wand->images->quality=quality;
  return(MagickTrue);
}
```

The method `setCompressionQuality` sets compression quality for the whole object. This method is a wrapper for `MagickWand`'s `MagickSetCompressionQuality` function. [Source code](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickWand/magick-property.c#L1980) is:

```
WandExport MagickBooleanType MagickSetCompressionQuality(MagickWand *wand,
  const size_t quality)
{
  assert(wand != (MagickWand *) NULL);
  assert(wand->signature == MagickWandSignature);
  if (wand->debug != MagickFalse)
    (void) LogMagickEvent(WandEvent,GetMagickModule(),"%s",wand->name);

  //This line sets quality for the image_info struct instance.
  wand->image_info->quality=quality;
  return(MagickTrue);
}
```

The `MagickWand` struct holds instances of `Image` and `ImageInfo` structs, [source](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickWand/magick-wand-private.h#L49):

```
struct _MagickWand
{
  ...

  Image
    *images;          /* The images in this wand - also the current image */

  ImageInfo
    *image_info;      /* Global settings used for images in Wand */
  ...
};
```

Both [`Image` and `ImageInfo`](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/image.h#L151) structs hold a `size_t quality;` data member. So for your example `setImageCompressionQuality` is perfectly fine.