# How to set compression quality for WebP images using PHP?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, webp

I want to create WebP images using ImageMagick and PHP. Unfortuneately I couldn't find out how to set the compression quality for a WebP image as the following code seems to ignore.

```
$quality = 1; # example which should result a low quality image

$imagick = new Imagick( $sourcefile );
$imagick->setImageFormat('webp');
$imagick->thumbnailImage( 850, 600, true );
$imagick->setImageCompressionQuality( $quality );
#$imagick->writeImage($file .'.webp');
```

The result image in poor quality but not as bad as 1% compression should be.

Any ideas/help on how to set image quality?

Kind regards,
Tom

Comment: See all the webp Imagemagick defines at https://imagemagick.org/script/webp.php. What type of image is your input? Is it PDF? If so, you then need to define the density to use to read and rasterize the PDF.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441364/what-is-difference-between-setimagecompressionquality-vs-setcompressionquality

Comment: @fmw42: This doesn't help as I don't use command line.

Comment: Post a link to your input file.

Comment: My input file is a large jpg, uploaded with a file upload form.